# ViewTableUI cell loading problem

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Helo! How can i convert a NSMutableArray object to a NSString ? i try to do something like

```
cell.textLabel.text = [cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But it doesn't work, my app crashes. If i do something like

```
cell.textLabel.text =@"yes";
```

The app loads very nicely(but instead of the elements from the "cars" NSMutableArray i have a view table filled with "yes") . Any idea what the problem is ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  That can tell alot about whats wrong.

Comment: Also some code of where you are initializing and filling your array would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the NSMutableArray alloc'd and init'd properly? If you don't call `cars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` before you use it, the array will not respond to adding objects to it. Make sure that's not the case. Also make sure that the elements in the cars array are NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `cards` contains enough cars, if the `indexPath.row` is large than the `cards`'s count-1, it will crash.